# Generate sets from given overlap matrix

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, set, overlap

**Note: I edited the original question to explain more precisely.**

While I was doing a simulation for my new method, I needed to generate a special type of dataset consists of multiple subset. The problem is that there is some "shared" variables across the subsets, and the number of shared variable is called "overlap" here. Since the distribution of overlap proportion is given, I need to generate an appropriate list of variables and their overlap follows the given distribution. But I have failed to implement such algorithm...

I am not sure whether there is a specific algorithm for this kind of question,
but I have failed to find such thing after a long search.

I prefer R solution, but anything others also will be very appreciated. Please help me to solve this problem! Thank you so much in advance!

The below is a standardized explanation for my problem. I tried to explain as general as possible I can, but please give me any suggestion if it is not sufficient.

**Purpose:** Generate **n** sets from given overlap matrix of elements. Each set contains **k** elements.

**Input:** There is a n*n matrix whose (i,j)th cell value represents a number of overlapped elements from (i)th set to (j)th set.

**Output:** A list of **k** element identifiers (whatever can be used such as number) for **n** sets.

**Assumption:** The number of elements for each set is **k**, and it is same across all **n** sets. Hence, the input matrix is symmetric.

**Example** (assumes k=3 and n=3)

Input

```
3 1 0
1 3 1
0 1 3
```

Output

```
Set 1: A B C
Set 2: A D E
Set 3: D F G
```

In the above example input, (1,2)th and (2,1)th cells are 1 because set 1 and 2 share "A" element and *vice versa*, and diagonal cells are 3(=k) because each set shares all elements with itself.

Comment: smells like homework, what code have you tried so far?

Comment: Makes no sense to me. Perhaps you should explain what the adjective "overlap" means to you and why the diagonal elements are `3`

Comment: @NateDay I wrote all of the above explanations examples by my own. First I thought there is some algorithm to solve this kind of problem, but I couldn't find any similar algorithms/methods but the reverse one. The reason I am trying this is because the simulation what I need to do requires generation of multiple subsets that shares some variables each other, and the distribution of that overlap is referenced.

Comment: @42- Apologizes my short explanation. Simply, here the "overlap" means the number of elements shared each other. Since I assumed k=3 and n=3 in my example, the diagonal cells are all 3 because the i-th group shares all elements with itself (since k=3).

Comment: @NateDay I tried get maximum of off-diagonal elements for each row and generate the shared elements according to that number, but it does not solves the problem exactly. Then I also tried a kind of divide-and-conquer approach by separating the entire matrix into block diagonal form and solve each block, but still it does not work. Now I am out of the idea.

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would repeat the following process until I had accounted for all the matrix entries:

1) Treat the matrix as the adjacency matrix of a graph, and find the largest clique in it. That is, find the largest possible set S of indexes such that for all i, j in set S M(i,j) > 0

2) Create an item that is in all of the sets which correspond to the indexes in S - in fact, if the minimum value of M(i,j) = v, create v such items.

3) subtract v from M(i,j) for all i, j in set S, accounting for the counts generated by the items you have just created.